# Support Vector Machine for Noisy neighbour detection in Openstack

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, svm, supervised-learning

What must the feature matrix (that is to be fed to the SVM classifier) comprised of, when you want to identify which VM (virtual machine) is the noisy neighbour in the multi-tenant cloud infrastructure? I am trying to form the feature matrix from the ceilometer logs from OpenStack. Can someone suggest what has to be done?

Comment: What data do you have in the ceilometer logs? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ceilometer metrics can contain many data, but my focus is on parameters that can identify a VM is a noisy neighbour or not. For instance, storage info can give one such insight

Comment: Are the storage data static (capacity of storage) or dynamic (storage at a given time)? Do you have any historical data when you know that a VM was a noisy neighbour?

Comment: Data is not static. I have to consider the storage usage by the VMs for sliding time windows. For instance, metrics are taken every 10 secs and are aggregated as 30 sec time period.

Comment: Ok. And do you have any labeled data indicating that a VM was a noisy neighbour?

Comment: yes @KarelMacek

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic nature of your data may require recurrent approach. If you are interested in SVM, you can adopt its recurrent version https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e1e8/ce51f3a7f3bc8fa23872f37a0e6d73cb4e55.pdf

However, you can take advantage of recurrent neural networks, too. LSTM may help.